# Access violation reading AVI file in opencv 2.1

Tags: c, opencv

I am tying to read an AVI file and display the frames in a window using opencv2.1 my code is as follows

```
#include "cv.h"
#include "highgui.h"
int main(int argc,char* argv[])
{
IplImage* grabedFrame = 0;
IplImage* savedFrame = 0;   

IplImage* destination1;
cvNamedWindow( "Demo", 1 );
CvCapture* capture = cvCaptureFromAVI("Star.avi");
const char* video = "Star.avi";
if( !capture )
{
    fprintf(stderr,"Could not initialize capturing...\n");
    return -1;
}
for(;;)
{
    counter++;
   frame = cvQueryFrame( capture );
    if( !frame )
       break;
    cvShowImage("CamShiftDemo",image);
}
cvReleaseCapture( &capture );
cvNamedWindow("ExtractedFrame",1);
cvShowImage("ExtractedFrame",savedFrame);
}
```

The problem is in the function cvQueryFrame.
For .avi files the program fails in a particular frame with the error Access violation reading location 0xffffffff.The strange thing is that some times the program run properly some times it fails with the access violation error . Please anybody help me with this . Thanks in advance.

Comment: The code shown won't compile. Also it's formatted badly.

Comment: Show `frame` declaration.